# are all the numbers in Euclid proof prime numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

in Euclid for infinite primes we define $p_0= 2, p_n = p_0p_1...p_{n-1}+1$ that way we get a series so that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we get that $p_n$ is divided by a prime not one of $ p_0,...,p_{n-1} $.

**my question** is: does for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we get that  $ p_n $  is a prime itself ?

i will be grateful if someone will give me a counterexample or a proof for this statement.

Comment: Trial and error should quickly get you a counterexample.

Comment: No. See what happens at (I think) $11$.

Comment: i dont think i can reach that level of calculation

Comment: To be clear:  this is NOT the usual construction found in Euclid.  Euclid takes the first $n$ primes and multiplies them together, adding $1$ to the product.  That is not what you have written.  Yours becomes composite almost immediately.  Unless I botched it, your $p_5=1807=13\times 139$ .  But maybe you defined $p_n$ incorrectly?

Comment: @lulu I think you mean $p_4=1807$ because the sequence starts with $p_0=2.$

Comment: @bof Yes, you are correct.  Doesn't change the counterexample though.

Comment: You wrote $p_n=\dots$ where you really want $p_n$ to be the $n$th prime.

Comment: Your assertion "$p_n$ is divided by a prime not one of $p_0,\dots,p_{n-1}$" would also be true if you simply defined $p_n=10^{n+1}.$ I think what you wanted to say was "$p_n$ is divided by a prime which does not divide any of $p_0,\dots,p_{n-1}.$"

Comment: 1) You've added an original twist and Euclid's construction... but no matter.  More importantly 2) Euclid's proof *doesn't* prove that $K=p_1p_2...p_n + 1$ is prime.  It proves that none of $p_i$ are prime factors of $K$.  And *that* in turn proves that as $K$ must have prime factors, there must be other primes than just $p_i$.  And as that can happen for any finite group of $p_i$ there must be an infinite number of primes.

Comment: we define $p0=2,p_n=p_0p_1...p_{n−1}+1$.  Actually, we never did any such thing.  We often (although Euclid did *not*) say let $p_0 =2; p_1 = 3, p_2 = 5$....so that $p_i =$ the $i$th prime and let $N = p_0...p_n + 1$.  *NO-ONE* ever claimed that $N$ was the $n+1$th prime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.
Your series starts by
$$2, 3, 7, 43, 1807, 3263443, 10650056950807, \ldots$$
and $$1807= 13 \times 139$$ $$10650056950807=547 \times 607 \times 1033 \times 3105.$$ Anyway
$$2\times3\times5\times7\times11\times13+1=59 \times 509$$